# How can I create a back end system used for adding hyperlinks and captions to images before their uploaded

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a back end form system in Php and mysql that will allow me to add  captions and hyperlinks on images before their uploaded to a web page.  The caption, hyperlink, and a reference to the image will be store in a mysql database. The form will only be used by me. How can I add hyperlinks and captions to images using a form so they can be upload to a web page? This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload form</title>
</head>
<?php
$add_link = $_GET['add_link'];
$add_caption = $_GET['add_caption'];

if(isset($_POST['upload_img'])) {
    $file_name = $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['image'] ['type'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['image'] ['size'];
    $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];

    if($file_name) {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,"img/$file_name");
    }
}
?>

<body>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>upload Image</label><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="image"><br><br>
        <label>Add link / URL to image:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="add_link" maxlength="30" size="30"><br><br>
        <label>Add text caption:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="add_caption" maxlength="30" size="30"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="upload_img">
    </form> <br>



    <?php
    $folder = "img/";
    if(is_dir($folder)) {
        if($handle = opendir($folder)) {
            while(($file=readdir($handle)) != false) {
                if($file ==='.' || $file ==='..') continue;

                echo'<a href="$add_link"> <img src="img/".$file."" width="150" height="150" alt=""><br>';
                echo $add_caption . "</a>"; 

            } 
            closedir($handle);
        }
    }


    ?>

    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,'image_display'))
{
echo 'Database not selected';
}

$add_link = $_GET['add_link'];
$add_caption = $_GET['add_caption'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO table1(image1,name,imagelink,caption,video) VALUES ('$add_link', '$add_caption', '$file_name')";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code with the problems fixed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload form</title>
</head>
<?php
// THESE TWO VARIABLES SHOULD NOT BE HERE     ◄■■■■■■■■■■
// BECAUSE WE DON'T KNOW IF THE EXIST. THEY   ◄■■■■■■■■■■
// BELONG TO NEXT IF.                         ◄■■■■■■■■■■
// $add_link = $_GET['add_link'];
// $add_caption = $_GET['add_caption'];

if(isset($_POST['upload_img'])) {
    // THE FORM IS "POST", NOT "GET".          ◄■■■■■■■■■■
    $add_link = $_POST['add_link'];            ◄■■■■■■■■■■ POST, NOT GET
    $add_caption = $_POST['add_caption'];      ◄■■■■■■■■■■ POST, NOT GET
    $file_name = $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['image'] ['type'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['image'] ['size'];
    $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];

    if($file_name) {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,"img/$file_name");
    }
 // THE DATABASE SECTION MUST BE HERE, INSIDE ◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
 // THE IF, NOT AT THE BOTTOM.                ◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,'image_display'))
    {
    echo 'Database not selected';
    }

    // THESE VARIABLES WERE ALREADY DECLARED.   ◄■■■■■■■■■■■
    // $add_link = $_GET['add_link'];           ◄■■■■■■■■■■■
    // $add_caption = $_GET['add_caption'];     ◄■■■■■■■■■■■

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table1(image1,name,imagelink,caption,video) VALUES ('$add_link', '$add_caption', '$file_name')";

    }
?>

<body>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>upload Image</label><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="image"><br><br>
        <label>Add link / URL to image:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="add_link" maxlength="30" size="30"><br><br>
        <label>Add text caption:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="add_caption" maxlength="30" size="30"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="upload_img">
    </form> <br>

    <?php
    $folder = "img/";
    if(is_dir($folder)) {
        if($handle = opendir($folder)) {
            while(($file=readdir($handle)) != false) {
                if($file ==='.' || $file ==='..') continue;

                echo'<a href="$add_link"> <img src="img/".$file."" width="150" height="150" alt=""><br>';
                echo $add_caption . "</a>"; 

            } 
            closedir($handle);
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```